# Scrapy choose from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, ajax, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to crawl this page https://www.stickyguide.com/dispensaries/leaf-lab/ using scrapy.
I am now having trouble crawling reviews from this page for a long time. If any one has any experience dealing with Ajax or Javascript, please share your thoughts.

1) I can easily get the Xpath for the review:

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="reviews_section"]/div')
```

However, I believe the review part of the page is loaded by javascript. Every time when I crawled this page, I got the following value of Xpath:

```
<Selector xpath='//*[@id="reviews_section"]/div' data=u'<div id="loader">\n<div class="loader"></'>
```

If there any method I can use to assure that scrapy crawls before javascript has been loaded?
When I looked up the method online, using selenium package may be a solution, but it may be not efficient.

2) Another problem I met is that I only want to crawl the data from dispensaries. I need to choose the option "VIEW: Dispensary Only" from the dropdown menu next to the Review module. I took a look at the HTML code and it tends out to be an Ajax object.

```
<select id="sort" name="sort" onchange="new Ajax.Request('/update_reviews_section/2487', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:'sort_by=' + $('sort').value + '&amp;authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('69BgJpnnj0tx/0lYwjIk75iFj0/l2R9EDj1No1FJX9o=')})">
```

If there any method I can use to request the content of the option "VIEW: Dispensary Only"?
I have tried a lot of methods on stackoverflow but I still can't work this out.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your dev tools (F12), look up where this piece of html is loaded from and just make request to get it. I can see that reviews are loaded with this request (POST to /update_review_section with three keys and values in form body), remember to keep checkbox 'preserve_log' in dev tool this will allow you to see what happens when page loads. See highlighted request in screenshot

:[image]

Comment: Currently I get the body of the html page like this: `new Ajax.Request('/update_reviews_section/2487', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:'sort_by=' + $('sort').value + '&authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('eVbHui2XbRZx9eMH9hABjsai3A42AGh8sWHa5wqbgAw=')})`
Then I do the regular expression extraction and get `request_url = 'https://www.stickyguide.com/update_reviews_section/2487'`, and `request_data = {'authenticity_token': 'eVbHui2XbRZx9eMH9hABjsai3A42AGh8sWHa5wqbgAw%3D', 'sort_by': 'VIEW%3A%20Dispensary%20Only'}`.

Comment: By calling `yield FormRequest(request_url, callback=self.RubiGuessItem, formdata=request_data)`, I still cannot get a appropriate response. Could you help me with this? I am new to scraping javascript. Thank you!